# Keeping up with the Joneses

Tags: translation, word, phrase, idioms, proverb

What is the best Chinese proverb or translation that would best capture the meaning of the English idiom "Keeping up with the Joneses"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**攀高**

*Oxford*

> 攀比 try to keep up with the Joneses
> 攀高心理
> a keeping up with the Joneses mentality